# How to reset fields after click on another div area?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  count=0;
  $('.clickme').click(function() {
    $("#popup_box2").reset();

    if(count==0) {
      $('#popup_box1').toggleClass('opacityfilter');
    }
    count++;
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
  count=0;
  $('.clickme1').click(function() {
    if(count==1) {
      $("#popup_box1").reset();
      $('#popup_box2').toggleClass('opacityfilter1');
      $('#popup_box1').toggleClass('opacityfilter');
    }
    count=0;
  });
});
```

These two divs contain some fields. When a user clicks on second div field of first div, it must be reset and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling on `jQuery` object call it on `DOM` object, you can also use jQuery [.get( index )](http://api.jquery.com/get/) to get the DOM object.

*Change*

```
$("#popup_box2").reset();
```

*To*

```
$("#popup_box2")[0].reset();
```

or

```
$('#my_table').get(0).reset();
```